# With Maven, how do you filter a file that is not a resource but you want it to use the same filters as resources?

Tags: java, spring, maven, resources, filter

With Maven, how do you filter a file that is not a resource but you want it to use the same filters as resources?

Here is my `resources` tag in my `pom.xml`. The first two are working fine, because I ultimately want these files to go into the classpath. However, with the 3rd and final `resource` tag, I want to make sure it goes into the `WEB-INF` directory rather than the `classes` directory. My code, which I thought ought to work, actually doesn't work. How can I make this happen?

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/dict</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>myapplication-servlet.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: where is `myapplication-servlet.xml` resides in your `src` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a webapp resource and should be dealt with as such by [configuring the maven war plugin appropriately](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html). Define the resource there and turn on filtering, and you'll get the results you expect.